# Bayesian estimation with python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, databricks, bayesian, probability-distribution

I am trying to use Bayesian estimate to calculate the following:

Suppose we produce a series of widgets, and run each through a set of quality control tests.

Each widget has an unknown probability *p* of failing each test. (Tests are independent given *p*.) We run a series of 1-3 tests. As soon as the widget passes one, it is considered acceptable. If it fails them all, it is considered a failure.

We have historical data about how previously produced widgets have done in these tests that can be used to estimate the distribution over *p*.

What should we compute to answer the question, "A widget has failed *k* tests already. What is the probability that it will fail all three?"

---

This is the code I tried already:

```
# Calculate the prior pass probability for each softbin
softbins_total_counts_df = softbins_df.withColumn('total', F.col('total_pass') + F.col('total_fail'))
prior_pass_prob = F.col('total_pass') / F.col('total')
prior_fail_prob = F.col('total_fail') / F.col('total')

# Calculate probabilities using Bayesian estimation with empirical prior
rho = 0.3
prior_window = Window.partitionBy('softbin_first_test').orderBy(F.col('time_window')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
prior_pass = F.mean(prior_pass_prob).over(prior_window)
prior_fail = F.mean(prior_fail_prob).over(prior_window)
alpha = prior_pass * (1 - rho) / rho
beta = prior_fail * (1 - rho) / rho
pass_prob = alpha / (alpha + beta)
```

Actually when I display the data the prior_pass is the same as the pass_prob (intuitivly because alpha + beta = 1 ) but how should i get this difference to have the pass_prob different from the prior_pass? some have an idea about the way to calculate the alpha and the beta...

Comment: How are the functions partitionBy, orderBy, and over defined? What model are you using? What are alpha, beta, and rho?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, i don't use a model yet here i tried to use the bayesian estimation to calculate the probability using alpha and beta.

Comment: the partitionby means that i group the data by 'softbin' and then i order it depending on time

Comment: We need way more information to go on. I'm guessing that you're using PySpark, since that's what turns up when I google "Window.partitionBy"? But we don't know what the format of your dataset is, so we can only guess at what prior_pass and prior_fail mean from the names. And you haven't said **what alpha, beta, and rho represent** (Bayesian estimation could refer to lots of methods), so all we can say is that you compute prior_pass / (prior_pass + prior_fail) (the rhos completely cancel out) and find that it's not equal to prior_pass. But we don't know why you expect them to be equal.

Comment: ideed i am using pyspark and i have a spark df and it is a parquet file. here is the link from where i get this information about alpha and beta (in the pdf are named shape1 and shape2) : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/VGAM.pdf page 63

Comment: what i mean bay prior pass is the probabilty that have calculated in the previous time (historical data) and same thing for prior fail. because my objective actually is to estimate the probability of an category to pass at retest and to estimate it i want to use historical data... that why i used the bayesian estimation

Comment: this probability it's represented using the bayesian estimation by pass_probability = alpha / alpha+beta   but the alpha is always equal to (alpha + beta) i don't know how to solve it

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what you're trying to do, but the 600 unformatted characters we can put in comments is proving rather limiting. Let's move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254783/bayesian-estimation-with-python)

Comment: I need at least 20 reputations to talk in the chat, an now i have just 17

Comment: I upvoted the question. That should give you enough.